# Как добавить в JS код яндекс карты метки из двух php массивов с координатами

Tags: javascript, яндекс-карты

Пытаюсь добавить в код яндекс карты метки объектов. Если вручную - все в порядке. Не могу понять как автоматически добавлять нужное количество объектов имея массивы с данными меток, широтой и долготой. Код одной метки выглядит так.

```
velomig = new ymaps.Placemark([55.740005,37.861097], {
    balloonContent: '<img src="/images/MapBannersDealers/velomig.jpg">',
    clusterCaption: 'Веломиг'
}, getPointOptions());
```

Название метки, координаты, содержимое балуна и подпись кластера.

Как мне сделать цикл, который бы перебирал все координаты из массивов и вернул бы объекты с подставленными значениями, что-то вроде

```
for (i = 0, i<longitude.length, i++ ){  
    name[i] = new ymaps.Placemark([longitude[i],latitude[i]],{
        balloonContent: ballon[i],
        clusterCaption: clusterCaprion[i]
    }, getPointOptions());
}
```

Comment: запуш php цыклом в массив js app.push(<?php echo array[i] ?>)

Comment: Это не то что вы хотите? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/672778/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-json-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0/672869#672869

Comment: А метки можете взять откуда нужно

Answer (score 1):

Не стоит смешивать PHP и JavaScript, сформируйте ваш массив и выведите его на страницу при помощи стандартной функции php - [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php), примерно так:

```
<?php

$dataArray = [
  [
    'coords' => [55.800434123328664,37.913230695312514],
    'title' => "Метка 1"
  ],
  [
    'coords' => [55.707629064640194,37.469839704628086],
    'title' => "Метка 2"
  ],
  [
    'coords' => [55.64865482240896,37.656607282753086],
    'title' => "Метка 3"
  ],
];

?>

<script type="application/json" id="map-points"><?=json_encode($dataArray)?></script>
```

На выходе должно получиться такое:

```
<script type="application/json" id="map-points">
  [
    {
      "cords":  [55.800434123328664,37.913230695312514],
      "title": "Метка 1"
    },
    {
      "cords":  [55.707629064640194,37.469839704628086],
      "title": "Метка 2"
    },
    {
      "cords":  [55.64865482240896,37.656607282753086],
      "title": "Метка 3"
    }
  ]
</script>
```

Затем вытащите эти данные и пройдитесь по ним циклом.

Рабочий пример тут https://codepen.io/lukas-pierce/pen/xgoYEY