# Как вывести точки на яндекс карте на основании json файла?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

День добрый!
Например, вот json файл data.json

```
{
"Points":[{
    "MapPoinName": "Город 1",
    "MapPointPopulation": 125000,
    "MapPointCoordinates": "58.211748, 59.979321"
}, {
    "MapPoinName": "Город 2",
    "MapPointPopulation": 105000,
    "MapPointCoordinates": "51.221748, 53.929321"
}]
```

}

Вывожу так:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Карта возможностей и проблем</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
     <style>
        html, body, #map {
            width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0; border: 2px red;
        }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

ymaps.ready(init);
function init () {
    var map = new ymaps.Map("map", {
            center: [55.76, 37.57],
            zoom: 5,
            controls: ['zoomControl','searchControl']
        });
// создадим массив геообъектов
myGeoObjects = [];

$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
 //console.log(data);
 for (var i = 0; i < data.Points.length; i++) {
  myGeoObjects[0] = new ymaps.GeoObject({
    geometry: {type: "Point", coordinates: [57.211748, 52.979321]},
    properties: {
        clusterCaption: 'Описание в кластере',
        balloonContentBody: [
            '<address style="font-style: normal">',
            '<h3>Данные</h3>',
            '<b>Данные: </b>МО "Название МО"<br>',
            '<b>Данные: </b>ФИО Главы МО<br>',
            '</address>' ].join('')
    }
    },
    {// Задаем пресет метки с точкой без содержимого.
    preset: "islands#darkGreenDotIcon",
});
 }
});
// создадим кластеризатор и запретим приближать карту при клике на кластеры
clusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer({preset: 'islands#invertedDarkGreenClusterIcons', clusterDisableClickZoom: true, clusterBalloonContentLayoutWidth: 800, clusterBalloonLeftColumnWidth: 160});
clusterer.add(myGeoObjects);
map.geoObjects.add(clusterer);
//Спозиционируем карту так, чтобы на ней были видны все объекты
map.setBounds(clusterer.getBounds(), { checkZoomRange: true});
}
</script>
<div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Данные из json получаю, но код внутри for (var i = 0; i < data.Points.length; i++) не выполняется

Comment: Что значит не выполняется? не входит в цикл или же другая ошибка?

Comment: В консоли : TypeError: n is null

Comment: только что запустил код, работает. А Вы точно получаете json в ответе? попробуйте в консоли вывести `console.log(data.Points[0].MapPoinName);`

Comment: @MrFylypenko? у Вас вышло 2 точки? Координаты в примере одинаковые, должно быть 2 точки в одном месте.

Comment: визуально вижу только 1 точку

Comment: @MrFylypenko Видите только последнюю точку?  А сколько точек вам нужно вывести? и расстояние между ними какая? Потому что если будет большое расстояние то смисол есть уже показать карту?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример JavaScript кода для вывода точек с кластеризацией:

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
  var map = new ymaps.Map("map", {
    center: [55.76, 37.57],
    zoom: 5,
    controls: ['zoomControl', 'searchControl']
  });
  $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
    // Создадим объект точек из data.Points
    var myGeoObjects = data.Points.map(item => {
      return new ymaps.GeoObject({
        geometry: {
          type: "Point",
          // Переведем строку с координатами в массив
          coordinates: item.MapPointCoordinates.split(', ')
        },
        properties: {
          clusterCaption: 'Описание в кластере',
          balloonContentBody: [
            '<address style="font-style: normal">',
            '<h3>Данные</h3>',
            '<b>Данные: </b>МО "Название МО"<br>',
            '<b>Данные: </b>ФИО Главы МО<br>',
            '</address>'
          ].join('')
        }
      }, {
        preset: "islands#darkGreenDotIcon",
      });
    })
    // Создадим кластеризатор после получения и добавления точек
    var clusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer({
      preset: 'islands#invertedDarkGreenClusterIcons',
      clusterDisableClickZoom: true,
      clusterBalloonContentLayoutWidth: 800,
      clusterBalloonLeftColumnWidth: 160
    });
    clusterer.add(myGeoObjects);
    map.geoObjects.add(clusterer);
    map.setBounds(clusterer.getBounds(), {
      checkZoomRange: true
    });
  })
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Yandex api Maps имеет вот такую хорошую функцию `addOverlay` при помощи которой можно добавить точки на карте.

Сделал стандартную инициализацию `yandex api maps` первой точкой сделал текущую геопозицию пользователя,
Потом после парсинга json данных циклом проходим по нему и добовляем наши метки на карте, после добавления всех меток рисуем карту с заданными данными.

```js
var points_json = '{"Points":[{"MapPoinName": "Город 1","MapPointPopulation": 125000,"MapPointCoordinates": "58.211748, 59.979321"}, {"MapPoinName": "Город 2","MapPointPopulation": 105000,"MapPointCoordinates": "51.221748, 53.929321"}]}';
    var points = $.parseJSON(points_json);
    // Создание обработчика для события window.onLoad
    YMaps.jQuery(function () {
        // Создание экземпляра карты и его привязка к созданному контейнеру
        var map = new YMaps.Map(YMaps.jQuery("#YMapsID")[0]),

            // Центр карты
            center,

            // Масштаб
            zoom = 10;

        // Получение информации о местоположении пользователя
        if (YMaps.location) {
            center = new YMaps.GeoPoint(YMaps.location.longitude, YMaps.location.latitude);

            if (YMaps.location.zoom) {
                zoom = 3;
            }

            map.openBalloon(center, "Место вашего предположительного местоположения:<br/>"
                + (YMaps.location.country || "")
                + (YMaps.location.region ? ", " + YMaps.location.region : "")
                + (YMaps.location.city ? ", " + YMaps.location.city : "")
            )
        }else {
            center = new YMaps.GeoPoint(37.64, 55.76);
        }
        for(var i=0;i < points.Points.length;i++){
            var tmp_points = points.Points[i]['MapPointCoordinates'].split(', ');

            var placemark = new YMaps.Placemark(new YMaps.GeoPoint(tmp_points[0],tmp_points[1]));

                placemark.description = "point "+i+" description";
                map.addOverlay(placemark);

            center = new YMaps.GeoPoint(tmp_points[0], tmp_points[1]);

        }
        // Рисуем карту
        map.setCenter(center, zoom);
    });
```

```html
    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script charset="utf-8" src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/1.1/index.xml" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div style="width:600px;height:400px" id="YMapsID" class="YMaps YMaps-cursor-grab"></div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Более подробно об этом можете прочитать [здесь](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/quick-start/tasks/quick-start-docpage/?from=techmapsmain).