# Редактирование Яндекс.Карт

Tags: javascript, html, css, яндекс-карты

Можно ли редактировать/кастомизировать бесплатную версию **Яндекс.Карт** на сайте?
Например, изменить цвет фона или изменить кнопки.

Comment: может поможет, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/672778/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-json-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0/672869#672869

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/company/yandex/blog/255279/ вот информация по поводу правок карт Яндекс

Answer (score 1):

https://yandex.ru/legal/maps_api/20120730/ п. 2.3.6.5
https://yandex.ru/blog/mapsapi/kak-perekrasit-yandeks-kartu-v-serye-tona/589410fbca07960017f1e796

> Перекрашивать карту запрещено условиями использования.
>   При обнаружении подобного доступ к АПИ может быть прекращен